# JSF Mojarra is not initializing ManagedBeans in JBoss modules

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

My problem is (as I think) quite complicated..

I am using JBoss 7 and created a module for Liferay faces. Within my WAR file, I created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml, in which I load the JSF module with Mojarra and the Liferay Faces module. But on startup of my web application, the ManagedBeans of the Liferay Faces implementation are not initialized and because of this, my application crashes. If I include the Liferay Faces JAR in my WAR lib folder, everything works, so this something of a class loading issue..

Liferay Faces modules.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.liferay.faces">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="liferay-faces-alloy.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="liferay-faces-bridge-api.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="liferay-faces-bridge-impl.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="liferay-faces-portal.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="liferay-faces-util.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="util-bridges.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="util-java.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="util-taglib.jar"/>
              <!-- Just for testing --->
        <resource-root path="AlexBean.jar"/>

    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api" />
        <module name="javax.faces.api" />
        <module name="javax.inject.api" />

        <module name="com.liferay.portal" />

        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
[...]
<module name="com.liferay.faces" services="import" export="true" meta-inf="export"/>
<module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
[...]
```

Why do I know Mojarra is not scanning and loading the @ManagedBeans @ApplicationScoped as it should? The JAR file AlexBean.jar contains a single class which is annotated as @ManagedBean and @ApplicationScoped. If the JAR file is placed within the WAR file, it works. If I use the JBoss modules they aren't, so I assume that the Liferay Faces beans aren't loaded either, but they are needed..

Thx in advance!

Best regards - Nuker

Comment: Why do you think that what you are trying to do is even possible? An assumption? Otherwise state your sources. It seems logical to me that whatever bean needs to be managed by the JSF instance that manages your particular application (of potentially multiple applications running in the same instance), you need to deploy the classes as part of that specific application archive.

Comment: Did you create jandex index for your module? Otherwise annotations wont work.

Comment: Jandex index?? I never heard about that and Google also didn't find anything about Jandex..

Comment: @Gimby No, this is not an assumption from me, but an assumption from Neil Griffin from Liferay. He mentioned the auto load of ApplicationScoped beans of Mujarra to test if Mojarra is loading correctly. Here is the according forum thread https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32970576